# Pandas.DataFrame.groupby.sum() drops columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

| Assignment | Reference | Amount | Order reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB017648 | 90317000 | 1,579.54 | PEN |
| BB017648 | 90748514 | 3,999.00 |  |
| BB017648 | 90317000 | 540.21 |  |
| BB001947 | 90464822 | 33,003.89 | PEN |
| BB017244 | 90687323 | 10.16 | REJ |

I would like to perform a "pivot table like" aggregation on the column "Reference".
I tried this using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

wb = pd.read_excel("file.XLSX")
wb = wb.groupby("Reference").sum()
```

However, the result drops the columns "Order Reason" and "Assignment" and only shows the Reference and Amount.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: While performing sum over group (using group by) only numerical column can perform the operation and hence non-numerical columns will be dropped by default

Comment: Firstly, welcome to StackOverflow. Did you try `df["Reference"].sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby more than one column.  Something like this should get what you want?

```
wb.groupby(["Reference", "Order reason", "Assignment"]).sum()
```

Comment: I solved the issue. I added "numeric_only = False" as an argument to sum()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).